# For $f=u+iv$, if $u$ and $v$ are continuously differentiable and $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation, then $f$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I was following the proof by Stein, and wondering where we used the condition of continuity.

So he starts by decoding differentiability of $u$ and $v$, saying that

$$u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{du}{dx}h_1 + \frac{du}{dy}h_2+\mid h\mid\psi_1(h)$$ and

$$v(x+h_1,y+h_2)-v(x,y)=\frac{du}{dx}h_1 + \frac{du}{dy}h_2+\mid h\mid\psi_2(h)$$

where $\psi_j (h)\to 0$ $(j=1,2)$ as $\mid h\mid$ tends to $0$ and $h=h_1+ih_2$

Then we use Cauchy-Riemann equation to show that $$f(z+h)-f(z)=(\frac{du}{dx}-i\frac{du}{dy})(h_1+ih_2)+\mid h\mid\psi(h)$$where $\psi(h)=\psi_1(h)+\psi_2(h)\to 0$ as $\mid h\mid\to 0$.

Where did we use the fact that derivative of $u$ and $v$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuity of the derivatives is not needed, unless they're using it to infer that $u$ and $v$ are differentiable.

Differentiability is sufficient, see Page 231 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.